# Error Building Multiple Android NDK Target with CMake

Tags: cmake, android-ndk

I am trying to build multiple ABI targets with NDK but keeps on getting error below.  Where and how do i debug the issue.   The error is "could not load cache"

I am using docker from [docker-android-ndk](https://github.com/saschpe/docker-android-ndk/blob/master/Dockerfile)  and [c source](https://github.com/LoupVaillant/Monocypher)

The Error
[image]

The script file

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /app
cmake -GNinja -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=$NDK_ROOT/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake -DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-21 /app 
cmake --build /app -v
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(monocypher)

set(MONOCYPHER_SRC_FOLDER "Monocypher/src")

set(MONOCYPHER_SOURCES
    "${MONOCYPHER_SRC_FOLDER}/monocypher.h"
    "${MONOCYPHER_SRC_FOLDER}/monocypher.c"
    "${MONOCYPHER_SRC_FOLDER}/optional/monocypher-ed25519.h"
    "${MONOCYPHER_SRC_FOLDER}/optional/monocypher-ed25519.c"
)


include_directories(${MONOCYPHER_SRC_FOLDER})

include(ExternalProject)

file(TO_CMAKE_PATH "${CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE}" toolchain_file)


 macro (setup_library library_name android_abi)
    ExternalProject_Add(${library_name}-builder
      SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}"
      BUILD_ALWAYS YES
      DOWNLOAD_COMMAND ""
      INSTALL_COMMAND ""
      UPDATE_COMMAND ""
      PATCH_COMMAND ""
      CMAKE_ARGS
        -DLIBNAME=${library_name}
        -DANDROID_ABI=${android_abi}
        -DCMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH=${CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH}
        -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}
        -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}
        -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=${toolchain_file}
        -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/android-build/libs/${android_abi}
        -D${PROJECT_NAME}-MultiBuild=ON
      BUILD_COMMAND
        ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build . --config Release
    )
   #add_library(monocypher_native SHARED ${MONOCYPHER_SOURCES})
   #set_property(TARGET monocypher_native PROPERTY ENABLE_EXPORTS 1)   
 endmacro()

 setup_library(${PROJECT_NAME}-v8a arm64-v8a ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH})

add_library(monocypher_native SHARED ${MONOCYPHER_SOURCES})
set_property(TARGET monocypher_native PROPERTY ENABLE_EXPORTS 1)
```

Comment: Please, do not use **images** for error messages. Instead, paste them into the question as **text**: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557.

Comment: When I posted it as code along with the others the system prevents me from posting as it complains that my whole post looks like only code.

Comment: As you could see from the output, while `cmake` is called from the directory `...-builder-build`, the last parameter for `cmake` is `/app` and it denotes the build directory where your (external) project is configured. (This is confirmed by the line "Build files has been written to /app"). But building the project still uses `...-builder-build` as build directory. Because that directory doesn't contain configured project, you got the "could not load cache" error. That `/app` parameter doesn't look like one added by ExternalProject. Something else adds that parameter.

Comment: I am pretty confused myself on how the CMakeLists works.   What I wanted is a CMakeList that allows compiling 4 Architecture in one pass.  Any suggestions on doing that is much appreciated.  Thank you.